# spark.executor.cores can't take effect while using livy

Tags: apache-spark, executor, cpu-cores, livy

I'm using livy-server-0.2 to run spark job, however, I can't change the default setting for spark.executor.cores, it can't take effect while the other settings can.

It always use 1 core to start an executor.

```
yarn     11893 11889  6 21:08 ?        00:00:01
/opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java -server -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill 
%p -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/hadoop-yarn/cache/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1487813931557_0603/container_1487813931557_0603_01_000026/tmp 
-Dspark.driver.port=51553 
-Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1487813931557_0603/container_1487813931557_0603_01_000026 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend 
--driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.1.1.81:51553 --executor-id 19 
--hostname master01.yscredit.com --cores 1 --app-id application_1487813931557_0603 
--user-class-path file:/var/lib/hadoop-yarn/cache/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1487813931557_0603/container_1487813931557_0603_01_000026/__app__.jar
```

Here is my spark-defaults.conf file in $SPARK_HOME/conf

```
spark.master=yarn
spark.submit.deployMode=cluster
spark.executor.instances=7
spark.executor.cores=6
spark.executor.memoryOverhead=1024
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1400
spark.executor.memory=11264
spark.driver.memory=5g
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=600
spark.speculation=true
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1400
```

can anybody help me? thanks!

Comment: In livy source code, I see it will reads two configure files, livy-client.conf and spark-defaults.conf. And livy-client.conf has higher priority than spark-defaults.conf. However, it is not the root cause for setting not take effect because I also set the setting spark.executor.cores in defaults.conf. I assume there must be a configuration for spark.executor.cores somewhere.

Comment: can you please find a file called capacity-scheduler.xml in the cluster?

Answer (score 8):

I strongly advise you to read the Livy source code.I think Livy has little documentation , so ,you might meet many problems which cannot be solved by google.Livy is just a middleware， amount of code is relatively small.

You can specify the spark parameter from 3 locations:

- **Location A**: If you have already set the spark parameter in
  your creating-session post request to LivyServer ,then any
  configuration occured at your post request can not be overrided by any configuration file.That is to say, configuration at your post request has the highest priority;
- **Location B**: Then , at `$LIVY_HOME/conf`，you can set spark parameters
  like 'spark.driver.memory' at `spark-defaults.conf` or
  `livy-client.conf`;
- **Location C**: At last , Livy will also use configuration at
  `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`,but configuration here has the
  lowest priority,that is to say , only configuration that did't occur
  at Location A/B will take effect.

Comment: yes I ended up groking through the sources as well - my trouble was HiveMetastore not activating in EMR, there're several funny places like [this](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/551cc53095f0a4b5382602ba0c296f8cf8932e44/server/src/main/scala/org/apache/livy/server/interactive/InteractiveSession.scala#L347). So it seems that some of those livy.conf thingies in **B** just deliberately break **other** values set in **C**.

Answer (score 1):

There is a property in the yarn which limits the resource on the cluster.

```
sudo  vi /etc/hadoop/conf/capacity-scheduler.xml
```

Change the property to the following

```
"yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator": "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalcul‌​ator"
```

In order to make this property applicable you have to restart the yarn

```
 sudo  hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager stop
```

Restart the yarn

```
sudo  hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager start
```